# register/add host to chrome remote desktop extension host list using CRD API

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop

I've installed chrome remote desktop extension for desktop sharing.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher

Im very impressed. Its fast and easy.

There's an option to add your computer to My Computers list by Enabling remote connection. The computers in the lists are also called hosts, Google has also provide an API to add/update/list/delete the hosts. https://developers.google.com/chrome/remote-desktop/v1/reference/hosts/insert

Now my question is; has anyone able to add host/computer to host lists using the Google Chrome Remote Desktop API? If yes, can you help me out with this.

Please let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: send data in json format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it myself. I've used the php CURL for sending the host insert request. API only supports json content-type so you need to send data in json format.